# Application server and main methods

Tags: java, jvm, classloader, server, application-server

Suppose I start an application server and lunch a web page that is being deployed under this Applicatin server . This page have some links (urls) that call (each one) a diffrent main method in the Application sever deployed code (war) .
How does each main method "knows" not to start a new JVM but to run all under the Application Server JVM ?

Comment: Since when does a `main` method start a JVM instance? More likely a new JVM instance runs the specified `main` method during application start.

Comment: and what triggered a new JVM instance ?

Comment: *You* do. Either by calling `java -jar ...` or by starting the application server or something else.

Comment: right . ok . so my question : how my call to java myMain1Method not start a new JVM instance while code is running under the Application server JVM

Answer (score 1):

A Java web application deployed from a war file doesn't have multiple `main` methods (aka entry points). Each servlet or JSP (which is compiled to a servlet) is accessed by the `service` method (as documented in the Servlet specification as the Servlet life-cycle);

```
init()    // <-- called once
service() // <-- called multiple times, once for each request
destory() // <-- called once
```

The [Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html) documents the Servlet life-cycle in great detail.

Comment: as I mention : some web page has link that call:java myMain1Method , java myMain2Method  .. and so on. this has nothing to do with the servlet API

Comment: No. If it has nothing to do with the servlet API, why are you talking about war files? Post working code, because that can't be correct. Do you mean `javascript:`?

Comment: I will post the code . But do you claim war file can not have many main methods in many different classes in it ?

Comment: You can put as many `main` methods as you like in a war file, but **none** of them will ever be executed by a Web Application Server.

Comment: What do you mean :  by a Web Application Server ? The user hit the link and it call the main method. I will check exectly how the call looks like

Comment: An JEE container certified with the Web Profile. Apache Tomcat. WebSphere. Weblogic. JBoss. Etc.

Comment: yes sure , JBoss in this case .